# Extending divs slide behind

Tags: css, jquery-isotope

let me preface this by saying my CSS and JQuery experience is fairly limited.

I am using the JQuery framework Isotope to make a tiled layout page of Question and Answer content boxes. The answer is shown once the user clicks on the content box. The issue I am having is that when the answer is shown, it will slide behind other content boxes. I want it to push the other content boxes.

This [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gswanson/QJJ7b/28/) show the issue I am having. I'm not sure if it's a CSS issue or a issue with Isotope. but here is the Isotope code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(function () {
    var $container = $('#container');
    $container.isotope({
        itemSelector: '.qaItem',
        layoutMode: 'masonry',
        masonry: {
            columnWidth: 200,
            gutterWidth: 40
        }
     });
  });

  $('.qaItem').click(function () {
    $(this).children('.answer').slideToggle("fast");
  });
});
```

Any thoughts on how I correct this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Look at your `layoutmode`.

If you use `layoutMode: 'fitColumns',` it works fine.

You can also fiddle around with other layout modes.
A working example can be found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Lr5mV/).

You can learn more about layoutmodes [here](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/docs/layout-modes.html).

Comment: Hi Jean-Paul, the example jsFiddle looks like it is working but I noticed that the external resource file is linked to masonry and and javascript error of Object [object Object] has no method 'isotope' is being thrown in the background.

When I update the resource file to point to the Isotope js file then the output doesn't appear.